# Printing Documents in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, printing

So I've done my research, and it seems that in order to print documents from Visual Studio using VB, it's a very long and lengthy process of manually drawing every line, rectangle and String on the piece of paper.

Thing is, I sometimes need to print up to 20 pages at once, and there are several functions that require this. After spending a week on creating one such document manually, I've decided to ask two questions:

1) Is it possible to print from a HTML template instead, i.e. inputting a HTML String?

2) Barring that, is it possible to use VB to print from a document that's already existing? This way, I can look into the possibility of generating a document with a different language (hopefully HTML) and print that instead.

EDIT:

I am attempting to do this because the current printing capabilities of Visual Basic is too tedious (boxes and lines have to be drawn at specific x/y coordinates). I would like to speed up this process and hopefully use HTML with CSS styles to print. Is this in any way possible?

Comment: What format are the documents coming to you in?

Comment: You can use crystal report na?

Comment: or even Microsoft Reports. It comes with VS.

Comment: Erm... I'm just trying to print the documents. They are simply pure text with some formatting.

Comment: @Steve I'm trying to print the documents using a Windows Form though.

Comment: Your choices are: PrintDoc, Print the form, use a report like CR or MS, or pay for something 3rd party.

Comment: @Steve can I use CR or MR on Visual Studio Express? It seems like the easiest way to do things.

Comment: Reporting should comes with all versions. The question is what version of Visual Studio do you have? MS reports started on 2008 and on like 2010-2012, CR was no longer part of the install but you can get it from their site. If you have not worked with reports before, start with MS because it is lighter(smaller and easier install) and does not have some issues like CR (not x64).